# Why is my app saying the jquery file is missing even though it exists?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

I'm trying to run my rails app locallly, but when I run it I get the following error message:

```
  Sprockets::FileNotFound at /in /Users/asaignment/catarse       
   /app/assets/javascripts/application.js:19)    
     couldn't find file 'jquery.fixedmask'
```

However, my            application.js    includes the following.

```
//=require jquery.fixedmask
```

How can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 1):

Sprockets is looking for a file called `jquery.fixedmask.js` in the asset tree which includes the vendor folder. If jquery.fixedmask is coming from a gem then you should make sure that the gem installed and compatible with rails asset pipeline 3.1 or higher. Otherwise you'll need to copy the jquery.fixedmask file into your project.